# How to extract date time from sql and bind it to datetimePicker

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datetimepicker

I have saved dates from datetimepicker to sql in my windows form app with the format (dd-MM-yyyy). To edit date, I want to first fetch saved date and show in the datetimepicker control. Like if 28-03-2000 is saved in db then datetimepicker should show this same date and should understand the format dd-MM-yyyy. The code with which I am trying to do is as follows

```
birthday_search.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["Birthday"]).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

birthday_search is the name of datetimepicker. This gives error "String was not recognized as a valid datetime" because its itself picking the format MM-dd-yyyy which is turning out to be wrong.

Comment: Are you sure that `Birthday` field value isn't `NULL`?

Comment: yes... Its  saved in db

Comment: What is the DataType of the Dirthday field in your database? First we need to be sure it is defined as a datetime (or equivalent) type. Then we can make the appropriate conversions for the DateTimePicker. If you use Value then you need to feed it with a DateTime, then you can decide which format to show using the Format/CustomFormat properties. Remember, by itself a DateTime field has no format. It is the tool used to display it (database admin tool or DateTimePicker) that formats it to a suitable display for you

Comment: its nvarchar.........

Comment: That's really wrong. A date need to be stored in a date field. Now you should get that value from the database and use a CultureInfo to make sense of a string that should be interpreted as a date

Comment: `birthday_search.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["Birthday"]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the type of the field *Birthday*.
You say you have it as a NVARCHAR column. This is wrong for many reasons.

First the database is not able to do appropriate searches on that field. For example: is "28-12-2000" before "14-01-2001"? If you look at it as a string NO because 1 is before 2, but if you look at it as a Date then YES.

Then you will have troubles converting that value back to a datetime variable when loading it. The conversion will assume the CultureInfo of the machine where the conversion occurs. This could work correctly or not depending on the input. For example on my machine the string "04-06-2017" will be converted in the 4th of June, but on a machine where the culture info is set to MM-dd-yyyy the same string will be parsed to the 6th of April.

So you just need to change that field to a datetime type, store values as DateTime variables and read them back with

```
birthday_search.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["Birthday"]);
```

or

```
birthday_search.Value = (DateTime)reader["Birthday"];
```

No formatting involved here. A field of type datetime is assigned to a property of type DateTime. The formatting to display this value is the job of the Format and CustomFormat of the DateTimePicker. Of course this code doesn't consider the possibility of a NULL value.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

change the property **format** of your datetimepicker to **Custom** 
then add the following code:

`birthday_search.CustomFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy";`

```
birthday_search.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["Birthday"]).ToString());
```

Comment: And why are u converting this, if u directly write it in this format to the database **.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")** ?

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert string to datetime. It says this

Comment: By not giving this format it is assuming date as Month and month ad Date.

Comment: Maybe because u used **birthday_search.Text** which needs a string

Comment: I used Value too.. response is same

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert string to datetime.
I have set its datatype to nvarchar in db.. May be I'm getting this problem due to this

Comment: hm yea normally in sql dates are stored in date. Try to store the result of your sqldatareader in a var. Then set a breakpoint in that line and see whats in there...

Comment: Problem resolved. I changed datatype to date and without doing any extra effort its returning me accurate result

Answer (score 0):

try setting the format of the datetimepicker like this:

```
birthday_search.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
```

and now your desired format:

```
birthday_search.CustomFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy";
```

Comment: Then to extract should I write this?
birthday_search.Value = reader["Birthday"]

Comment: birthday_search.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
      birthday_search.CustomFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy";
      birthday_search.Value = (DateTime) reader["Birthday"]

Its says specified cast is not valid

Comment: Problem resolved. I changed datatype to date and without doing any extra effort its returning me accurate result

Comment: Thank you for your effort :)

Answer (score 0):

The `dd-MM-yyyy` is not expected format for `ToDateTime` function by default. Use [`Convert.ToDateTime (String, IFormatProvider)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9xk1h71t(v=vs.110).aspx) overload instead. Or use [ParceExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) to get DateTime value:

```
DateTime MyDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(reader["Birthday"], "dd-MM-yyyy", null);
```

But in your case the conversion isn't necessary, becouse you could use string value for the `Text` property. So it's enough to use

```
birthday_search.Text = reader["Birthday"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
Me.birthday_search.DataBindings.Add("Text", TableName, "Birthday")
```

Comment: What does this add to the information in the contribution marked as "the answer"? Why should it solve the problem stated in the question? Please use the [edit] link below your answer to add this additional information.